# Magento 2.3 venia theme bugs

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio, venia, help-wanted

I have successfully Magento 2.3 venia theme with my backend URL. And every query was validated and theme working successfully. But the issue is I could not add products in the cart. This 400 error is what I got.

```
POST /rest/V1/guest-carts/Hrx6ctErQTVBWkrTU6A8rlWyj4NfA1WN/items 400 3173.894 ms - 755
```

Also, product images return

```
GET /media/catalog/product/ 404 2875.405 ms - 7259
```

I couldn't even guess what is the issue, I need some react or Magento experts
advice or help.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue ? @Ramesh KR

Comment: When do you get this error, during checkout or adding product to cart? I got this error during checkout and All I did is set braintree sandbox details in admin and .env file of venia theme and it worked without issues.